# Motionlayout: WARNING could not find view id -1

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-animation, android-motionlayout

My problem is, that I constantly get the warning `W/MotionLayout: WARNING could not find view id -1`. Because of this, my MotionLayout is really laggy and nearly jumps from the `expanded state` to the `collapsed state`. After waiting a couple of seconds, the animation starts getting better (no jumping / laggs anymore), but the warning remains.

### Base XML

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="product"
            type="com.example.app.framework.datasource.models.product.Product" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/shop_motion_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/shop_item_content_scene"
        app:showPaths="true"
        tools:context=".framework.ui.view.fragments.shop.ShopItemFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/shop_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:menu="@menu/shop_item_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="142dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard8dpMargin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:loadImage="@{product.images[0]}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shop_toolbar" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="@{product.name}"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/scrollview_shop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/margin_left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/product_image"
            tools:text="Long text to test some stuff etc. bla bla" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_shop"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/color_btn_blue"
            android:insetLeft="0dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetRight="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_filled"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconPadding="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/scrollview_shop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/scrollview_shop"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Example.Button.Circle" />

        <!-- My scrollview -->
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_shop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/product_name">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/someID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_article_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard8dpMargin"
                    android:text="FISCH"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_text_gray"
                    android:textDirection="locale"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal2"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="A 1234567" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_mwst_disclaimer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard8dpMargin"
                    android:text="SEIFE"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_text_mwst"
                    android:textDirection="locale"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal4"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/product_article_number"
                    tools:text="PREIS" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="left"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="btn_shop" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/margin_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/big16dpMargin" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</layout>
```

### ContentScene XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:onTouchUp="stop"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/scrollview_shop"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />

        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                app:motionTarget="@id/product_image"
                app:framePosition="40"
                android:alpha="0.0" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded" />

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/product_image"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/standard8dpMargin"
            android:scaleX="0.925"
            android:scaleY="0.925"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/shop_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/shop_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/btn_shop"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/shop_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/product_name" />
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

### Fragment

```
class ShopItemFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_shop_item) {
    private val productArgs by navArgs<ShopItemFragmentArgs>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = FragmentShopItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
        product = productArgs.product
    }.root

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initToolbar()
    }

    private fun initToolbar() = shop_toolbar.apply {
        setupWithNavController(findNavController(), AppBarConfiguration(findNavController().graph))
    }
}
```

### Expanded

[image: Expanded]

### Collapsed

[image: Collapsed]

### EDIT

I've tried to debug my code as good as I can and I found following: In my view, the `mConstraintSetId` has the value `-1`, and I think that logcat is warning me about that. How can I change this value or to say better: Why is this value -1?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

### The Issue:

The main thing you needed was not not be using both `app` and `motion` xml namespaces mixed in the same `MotionScene`:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

You can use either, but you have to stick with one. I prefer `app` - makes it easier for me to jump between layout XML and motion scene XML.

As it stood, because you were using both, MotionLayout just picked up attributes tagged with `app` and disregarded `motion` ones, which meant your instructions for `OnSwipe` were the same as this:

```
<OnSwipe app:onTouchUp="stop" />
```

That's why you were seeing the `WARNING could not find view id -1`, which probably means MotionLayout needs a better error message in that case, or shouldn't compile at all if more than one namespace is used.

---

### Solution:

So let's say you delete `motion` namespace, then all you have to do is update the `OnSwipe` transition to this:

```
        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:onTouchUp="stop"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/scrollview_shop"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />
```

And then your transition should run just fine.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much. I gave up on motionlayout because of this. But I have another question: My scrollview is ALWAYS scrolling, even when there is nothing to scroll. Do you know how I can "disable" the scroll behavior, when there is nothing to scroll e.g the view does not take more space than one screen? Currently, my view always scrolls and executes the animations

Comment: Don't give up, there's (probably) always a way.

Comment: Woops, meant to continue:

I think in that case you'd need to add a Transition + ConstraintSet that do not change the header at all, and then programmatically switch between transitions based on whether there are items to scroll or not. Don't think there is a way to do it in just XML.

Comment: Hmm okay, but I think there has to be a way. I know a app "Notebooksbilliger.de" which actually achieves this behavior (Collapsable toolbar + animation and only scrolling when there is something to scroll). If you install the app and click at one of their products you will see what I mean.

Comment: As I mentioned above ^ there is a way to do it by adding another ConstraintSet.

Another way which is a bit of a hack but doesn't require changing out transitions is just to hide the entire MotionLayout and show an empty state underneath. This is less efficient from a drawing perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the same `<Constraint ../>` in both `<ConstraintSet ../>`

Please try to update you scene and add:

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded" >
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/product_image"
        .... />
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/product_name"
        .... />

    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/btn_shop"
        .... />
</ConstraintSet>
```